# Replace a value in a random position with specific with restriction

Tags: shell-script

I need to replace randomly 10 % of a numbers in a column with other specific one. 
e.g. randomly replace 10%  of any number with "1" except in first position

in file1.txt

```
1 1234567890
2 0987654321
```

out file2.txt

```
1 1234561890
2 0987651321
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to replace individual digits in the whole number?

Comment: Yes I have codes of single digits from 0 to 6 and I want to add noise of the codes by replacing randomly 10%  of any code with a value that is not in a code list (for example 8)

Answer (score 0):

Save the following script as repwith1.sh:

```
cat | while read procl
  do echo -n "${procl:0:1}"
     for i in `seq 1 $((${#procl}-1))`
       do if [ $((RANDOM%10)) -eq 1 ]
             then if echo "${procl:$i:1}" | grep -q "[0-9]"
               then echo -n "1"
               else echo -n "${procl:$i:1}"
             fi
             else echo -n "${procl:$i:1}"
          fi
       done
     echo ""
  done
```

Use it like this:

```
$ cat (file name) | bash repwith1.sh
```

If you want to save to a file, do:

```
$ cat (file name) | bash repwith1.sh > (new file name)
```

Comment: IT is working but a bit wired. It is not considering the values in  the last row, and it is not always 10% of number of values in the single line.